# MySQL - Running multiple update queries over the same subset of large table

Tags: mysql

I have a large growing table (currently 14 million rows and counting).  It is a list of 'errors' from a log.   Some of these errors are known issues that I want to filter while they are fixed upstream.  In the table I have two bits 'CheckedForFilter' and 'Filtered'   I want to do the following in 10,000 row blocks.

```
 1) Select on 10,000 rows (where 'CheckForFilter' is false)
 2) Run a series of queries that set the 'Filtered' bit in certain criteria is true
 3) After the last query runs set the 'CheckForFilter' bit to true
```

The list of queries that could set the 'filtered' bit is currently 5 but I think over time it will grow.  My core issue is that I dont know how to select the same set of rows each time.  I need to keep the queries as a managable size because queries that run too long delay the servers replication.

Comment: hmm.. it sounds like maybe there is a regex pattern that will do your filtering?  if there are multiple patterns - then you could possibly store them in another table then just compare them all dynamically in a cursor.

Comment: another thought - do some bitwise indication of what filter was applied in the CheckedForFilter value (or change that to be more values) to indicate which filters have been checked - then you dont care so much about the same exact set each run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an ID field on your errors table you could do this.

Create a "filters" table which will contain the min and max ID values for the next 10,000 IDs to be checked.  Have a flag in this table called "Checked" which determines if all the filters have been checked yet.

Run your filter queries where the IDs in your error table are between the min and Max ID values in your "filters" table where the "Checked" field = 0.

Once you are done, update the CheckedForFilters flag on these records within the min and max ID range from your "filters" table.

Update the "filters" table and set the "Checked" field = 1.  You could also stored the date and time if you wish.

Run this for the next 10,000 records until done.

This would also allow you to keep a history of when the filters were run.  If you wanted to you could also store in a separate table which filters were run for each of these batches.

Comment: Thanks.. I had thought about something like this or creating a table that could hold 10,000 keys.  My hope when posting the request was to find something that would lock on to a set of rows and run multiple queries on it but certainly this would make a good alternate